# Air API to fetch flight class and its price information

Tags: sabre

I am pretty new to using Sabre Air APIs. I am trying to do a proof of concept to identify the APIs that can be used to book a flight. Documentation recommends to use Orchestrated APIs to reduce complexity.

My question here is about how to get flight class (eg economy, business etc) availability and its price information. I don't see those results coming from InstaSearch flight & Bargain Finder APIs

It would be helpful if someone can guide me on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main availability service would be OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ, that service will display the available booking classes for each flight. To obtain prices, you would use OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ. Orchestrated services combine both by using them together under EnhancedAirBookRQ, with enhanced logic and improvements.

The usual booking flow would required you to use 1) availability (OTA_AirAvaiLLSRQ or any shopping service like BFM); 2) add passenger details (you could use PassengerDetailsRQ); 3) book available space (OTA_AirBookLLSRQ); 4) price (OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ); 5) issue tickets (AirTicketRQ).

There are instances where you would need to use EndTransactionLLSRQ to commit changes into the PNR as well. I would advise to contact your account team for a basic PNR training.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It helped me to understand the working of APIs. However I don't find any API that fetch airline baggage, meals and Lounge information. Is it something that is outside Sabre? And where can I find complete SOAP request / response schema for all SOAP based APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the API Workflows documentation. There are examples to the use cases you call out.

https://beta.developer.sabre.com/solutions/workflows/low-fare-search-and-book